# How to work with Lightswitch projects in Visual Studio 2017 professional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-lightswitch

Hellow all, I am using Visual Studio 2017 professional edition. I am unable to open Lightswith (.lsxtproj) projects from it. When I searched in blogs, I received a suggestion of installing the **Office Developer Toos for Visual Studio** using Visual Studio installation window--> Individual Components --> Development activities section but couldn't help.

Can someone tell me what else I sould install/add in order to open Lightswitch projects using Visual Studio 2017 professional edition.

Comment: as far as I am aware, Lightswitch has actually been discontinued. The last version that supports it is Visual Studio 2015. I haven't installed the 2017 version myself, so may be wrong, but im guessing that is why. Its still a very good tool though and is leaps and bounds ahead of what the majority of people use now.

Comment: @Crezzer7 thanks for your reply. Pl. verify the same in VS-2017 when the time permits and share your answer. thanks again. 
I tried both Community & professional though